# My logo image in my header isn't changing size when I define a smaller size in CSS

Tags: html, css

[Website Screenshot :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knUmO.png) My logo image is by default 264x84px. It's going in a header that is 69px high, and the height has been defined as 50px, but the logo won't change size. It's bigger than the header

I've tried setting max-height and messing around with that, and then just setting it even smaller to see if that helped, but it won't resize at all

///html///

```
<div class='heading'>
        <a class='logo' href="../index.html"><img src="img-tea-cozy-logo.png"></a>
```

///html///

///css///

```
.logo {
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.heading {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
    height: 69px;
}
```

///css///

I don't understand why the image is staying the same size

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set the height of the image directly or set object-fit on it.
The current way the images will expand over the borders of the parent element.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly it

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the height of the link instead of the height of the image inside the link.

Change

```
.logo {height: 50px;}
```

to

```
.logo img {height: 50px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.logo {
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

.heading {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
    height: 69px;
}

.heading img {
    height: 100%;
    /* or */
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set the image height to 50px

```
.logo img {height: 50px;}
```

Whereas this will set the link height to 50 px

```
.logo { height: 50px;}
```